# Override Context Path in Spring Boot / Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

In Spring Boot / Tomcat is it possible to override the context-path (`server.servlet.context-path=/api`) specified in my `application.properties` for a single `@RequestMapping`?

My current context path is `/api` for the core application, but I have a public-facing portion of the API that I'd like to expose as `/id` and not `/api/id`.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot 2.x,  all it takes is a single property in application.properties:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

With Spring Boot 1.2+ (<2.0)

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api
```

ref link : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.changing-base-uri

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have an existing context-path of `/api`, but I am hoping to override it to be `/id` for one particular endpoint.